# Python: Adding values to empty dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have scraped a data from website and I would like to save all of data. However, it only saves the last value of the data. I have made an empty dictionary but i'm struggling with adding element in empty dictionary

Here's my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/')
    source.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')


    movies = soup.find('tbody', class_="lister-list").find_all('tr')    
    
data = {}

    for movie in movies: 
        
        name = movie.find('td', class_='titleColumn').a.text
        
        rank = movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").get_text(strip=True).split('.')[0] 

        year = movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").span.text.strip('()')

        rating = movie.find('td', class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").strong.text
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print(data)
```

Answer (score 2):

Close to your goal, simply add the information to your dict and append it with each iteration to a list. So you are able to create a dataframe:

```
for movie in movies:

    data.append({
        'name': movie.find('td', class_='titleColumn').a.text,
        'rank': movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").get_text(strip=True).split('.')[0],
        'year': movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").span.text.strip('()'),
        'rating': movie.find('td', class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").strong.text
    })
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/')
source.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')

movies = soup.find('tbody', class_="lister-list").find_all('tr')
data = []

for movie in movies:

    data.append({
        'name': movie.find('td', class_='titleColumn').a.text,
        'rank': movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").get_text(strip=True).split('.')[0],
        'year': movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").span.text.strip('()'),
        'rating': movie.find('td', class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").strong.text
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

##### Output

|  | name | rank | year | rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Die Verurteilten | 1 | 1994 | 9.2 |
| 1 | Der Pate | 2 | 1972 | 9.2 |
| 2 | The Dark Knight | 3 | 2008 | 9 |
| 3 | Der Pate 2 | 4 | 1974 | 9 |
| 4 | Die zwölf Geschworenen | 5 | 1957 | 8.9 |

....

Comment: @ChristianTrujillo: I understand your approach, and depending on the goal, it may have its charm. However, since `pandas` was listed as module, I strongly assume that any post processing will take place there, at least that's how I would do it, since many options such as simple filtering are open to you.

Answer (score 0):

you can replace your for loop with this one to add nested dictionaries, so you can find your movie info by name, then what info you wanted from it

```
for movie in movies:
    
    name = movie.find('td', class_='titleColumn').a.text

    data[name] = {}
    
    rank = movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").get_text(strip=True).split('.')[0] 

    year = movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").span.text.strip('()')

    rating = movie.find('td', class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").strong.text

    data[name]["rank"] = rank
    data[name]["year"] = year
    data[name]["rating"] = rating

print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to store the cur movie in data but make the name of the movie as a key

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy

try:
    source = requests.get('https://www.imdb.com/chart/top/')
    source.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')


    movies = soup.find('tbody', class_="lister-list").find_all('tr')    
    
data = {}

    for movie in movies: 
        
        name = movie.find('td', class_='titleColumn').a.text
        
        rank = movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").get_text(strip=True).split('.')[0] 

        year = movie.find('td', class_="titleColumn").span.text.strip('()')

        rating = movie.find('td', class_="ratingColumn imdbRating").strong.text
        cur = {
            'name': name,
            'rank': rank,
            'year': year.
            'rating': rating
        }
        # storing the cur movie in data but name of the movie as a key 
        data[name] = cur
        
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

print(data)
```